# Executing on-chain functions using react moralis

Tags: contract-invocation, nodejs, hardhat, react, moralis

I'm trying to convert my dapp from vanilla js + html (local hardhat node) to react-moralis + nextJS (local hardhat node).

Here is an example of a contract function call from the front-end. This code should create a new Event entity using provided params and ask for some gas in metamask. I hardcoded the params for now but when I call the function through an onClick on a button, metamask doesnt pop up:

```js
import { useWeb3Contract } from "react-moralis"
import contractAddresses from "../constants/contractAddresses.json"
import abiEvent from "../constants/abiEvent.json"
import { useMoralis } from "react-moralis"

export default function CreateMatch() {
    const teamName1 = "t1"
    const teamName2 = "t2"
    const teamName3 = "t3"
    const eventDate = "090909"
    const matchPlace = "msk"
    const matchFinished = false
    const matchBets = []
    const { Moralis, isWeb3Enabled, chainId: chainIdHex } = useMoralis()
    const chainId = parseInt(chainIdHex)


    const universalContractAddress = chainId in contractAddresses ? contractAddresses[chainId][0] : null

    const eventOptions = {
        abi: abiEvent,
        contractAddress: universalContractAddress,
        functionName: "createMatch",
        params: {
            teamName1, teamName2, teamName3, eventDate, matchPlace, matchFinished, matchBets
        },
    };

    const { runContractFunction, isFetching, isLoading } =
        useWeb3Contract();

    const { runContractFunction: createMatch } = useWeb3Contract();

    return (
        <div>Hi from CreateMatch
            <div>
                <button
                    onClick={() => runContractFunction({ params: eventOptions })}
                    disabled={isFetching}
                >
                    CreateMatch
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

and here is the contract that the code is intercating with:

```
pragma solidity 0.8.7;

contract Event {
    uint256 public matchCount = 0;
    mapping(uint => Match) public matches;

    struct Match {
        uint256 matchId;
        string homeTeam;
        string awayTeam;
        string drawTeam;
        string matchDate;
        string place;
        bool finished;
        address[] userList;
    }

    function createMatch(
        string memory homeTeam,
        string memory awayTeam,
        string memory drawTeam,
        string memory matchDate,
        string memory place,
        bool finished,
        address[] memory userList
    ) public {
        matches[matchCount] = Match(
            matchCount,
            homeTeam,
            awayTeam,
            drawTeam,
            matchDate,
            place,
            finished,
            userList
        );
        matchCount++;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone ever gets the same problem - I was sending parameters for my contract function incorrectly.
Here is what I should have done:

```js
  const eventOptions = {
    abi: abiEvent,
    contractAddress: universalContractAddress,
    functionName: "createMatch",
    //msgValue: 1,
    params: {
      homeTeam: "t1",
      awayTeam: "t2",
      drawTeam: "t3",
      matchDate: "0909",
      place: "msk",
      finished: false,
      userList: []
    }
  };
```